# Why do **2 and ² behave differently when using the cross meta-operator?

Tags: raku

The outcome are the same under currying,

```
say map * **2 , 1, 3, 5, 7, 9;
(1 9 25 49 81)
say map *² , 1, 3, 5, 7, 9;
(1 9 25 49 81)
```

On the other hand, the behaviors are different via the cross meta-operator,

```
say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X**2;
(1 9 25 49 81)
say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X²;
((1 2) (3 2) (5 2) (7 2) (9 2))
```

Why do **2 and ² behave differently when using the cross meta-operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `X` metaoperator takes the two lists it's given a combines them using the operator you give it. If you don't give it an operator it uses `,` as the default.

So in this case :

```
say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X²
```

The `X` metaoperator is looking for an infix operator. `²` isn't an infix operator it's postfix.

So `X` applies `,` as the operator. But now `²` is being evaluated as a list and in this case it's "this the number 2" property kicks in.

Basically these are the same :

```
say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X²
say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X, 2
```

If you want to square all the items in a list you want to use a `map` operator. As you did at the start.

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile on [IRC](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/raku?date=2019-11-21#l202)

> ```
> <Doc_Holliwood> m: ².WHAT.say
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «(Int)␤»
> <Doc_Holliwood> m: say 2 - ²
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «0␤»
> * abraxxa has quit (Ping timeout: 252 seconds)
> <Doc_Holliwood> where is the magic?
> <Doc_Holliwood> m: 2².say
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «4␤»
> <jnthn> I don't think there's any magic at all, it's just falling out of the standard parsing rules
> <AlexDaniel> u: ²⅓
> <unicodable6> AlexDaniel, U+00B2 SUPERSCRIPT TWO [No] (²)
> <unicodable6> AlexDaniel, U+2153 VULGAR FRACTION ONE THIRD [No] (⅓)
> <Doc_Holliwood> somewhere something must be actively distinguishing
> <AlexDaniel> so any No has a numeric value
> <jnthn> Well, the parser knows when it's looking for a term and when it's looking for a postfix
> <AlexDaniel> you can use these unicode characters (that are No) as numeric literals
> <AlexDaniel> and yeah, what jnthn said :)
> <jnthn> It can't be looking for a postfix if it didn't yet see a term
> <AlexDaniel> we had a few tickets about this, people find it very surprising, but the parser doesn't
> <Doc_Holliwood> so ² is sometimes an int and sometimes its a postfix depending on context?
> <tobs> by the same rule, it can distinguish between multiplication and whatever star
> <AlexDaniel> well, similarly, yes
> <AlexDaniel> m: say (* * *)(2, 8)
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «16␤»
> <jnthn> Doc_Holliwood: I guess, though only in the same sense that "+" in +$x is the numify operator, but in $a + $b it's the infix addition operator.
> <tobs> m: say 2²⁰
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «1048576␤»
> <jnthn> In general, the parser is always quite clear about what category of thing it would like to see next.
> <AlexDaniel> m: 2 2
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Two terms in a row␤at <tmp>:1␤------> 2⏏ 2␤  expecting any of:␤        infix␤        infix stopper␤       statement end␤        statement modifier␤        statement modifier…»
> <AlexDaniel> m: * 2
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Two terms in a row␤at <tmp>:1␤------> *⏏ 2␤  expecting any of:␤        infix␤        infix stopper␤       statement end␤        statement modifier␤        statement modifier …»
> <AlexDaniel> m: × 2
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Preceding context expects a term, but found infix × instead.␤at > <tmp>:1␤------> ×⏏ 2␤»
> <AlexDaniel> the error messages make it quite transparent :)
> <Doc_Holliwood> I'm just trying to wrap my head around the latest SO question. but it makes sense to me now. if ² ist a postfix, but X requires an infix. so X² cant DWTHAM
> <Doc_Holliwood> in order for say 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 X² to be 1 , 25, etc you would need to change how X works 
> *** <jnthn> m: say (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)>>² ***
> <camelia> rakudo-moar ed8f5141f: OUTPUT: «(1 9 25 49 81)␤»
> <jnthn> Just use something that expects a postfix op :)
> ```